# Get monthly availability in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, availability

There does not seem to be a way to query/output the availability of a monitored web application via MS Application Insights for a given month, even if it is the current month.
I'd think this would be one of the (if not THE) most important metric to monitor, so I can't imagine that this just isn't possible. What am I overlooking?

Application Insights's Analytics area seems to be limited to queries of just over a week, as is the detail data for a Web Test if one increases the time range.

Is there really no way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Application Insights Export](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-telemetry/) feature to bypass 8 days retention and store the results externally. As per documentation, this functionality exports web test results as well, so you'll be able to access them for as long as you store them.

Sorry if this sounds like a workaround (because it is) rather than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Feb 2017] Data retention is now 90 days.

Comment: Correct. There is default 90 days retention for all Tiers of the service and should help with this scenario